# Setting up a log for additions, deletions, and alterations to a database

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I want to have a text file document the activity of a MySQL database. I am using sqlalchemy to interface with the database. What I currently have (which is very rudimentary and not finished) is a function that adds an entry and then documents that entry along with the time.

```
def sess_commit(name, entries):
#This function has features to log entries to the database
#not the ideal way, but I will work on finding a better one.

    filepath = 'filepath' #location of our 'logger.txt'
    f = open(filepath)
    sess = create_session(name)
    sess.add_all(entries)

    for item in entries:
        f.write(str(item) + ' ' + str(datetime.now()))

    f.close()
    sess.commit()   
    sess.close()
```

Eventually, I would add more functionality and nuance so that it logs more than just entries, but does anyone know if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: may be you are looking for [logging] module [https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html]

Comment: Instead of logging yourself can try parsing the binary log: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html

Comment: Thanks @ZdaR I have found this module to best suit my needs

Answer (score 0):

You could turn MySQL general_log on instead. However, it would log all client connections and every single SQL query.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html